# How can i make spacy not produce the -PRON- lemma?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, text-processing, spacy

I am using spacy in order to lemmatize a large amount of tweets.  However when i lemmatize words like "I", the token -PRON- is produced.  How can i avoid that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-PRON-` is the default lemma for pronouns in spaCy (see the [docs](https://spacy.io/api/annotation)):

> About spaCy's custom pronoun lemma
>
> Unlike verbs and common nouns, there’s no clear base form of a personal pronoun. Should the lemma of “me” be “I”, or should we normalize person as well, giving “it” — or maybe “he”? spaCy’s solution is to introduce a novel symbol, -PRON-, which is used as the lemma for all personal pronouns.

If you don't want it, you can simply replace it by something else, such as the word form of the token in question (see code snippet below). Just be aware that this may have unexpected consequences for subsequent processing. spaCy uses both a string and an integer representation of token attributes, so you may want to change both of these (if possible), or keep the original integer value for traceability.

```py
if token.lemma_ == '-PRON-':
    token.lemma_ = token.orth_ # change the string representation
    token.lemma = token.orth # change the integer representation (I didn't test this part)
```